# Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qtcpsocket

I have a QThread defined in MyThread.cpp and .h. There I have a private QTcpSocket.

```
class MyThread: public QThread {

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyThread();
    virtual ~MyThread();

public slots:
    void reconnect();
signals:

protected:
    void run(void);

private:
    QTcpSocket *socket;
};

void MyThread::run(void) {
    bool connected = false;

    connected = prepareSocket(QString::fromLatin1((Global::directionIPSerialServer).toLocal8Bit().data()), 8008, socket);
}
```

On the other hand, I have a set of functions defined in Functions.cpp and .h, which are not defined into a Functions class, but a namespace.

```
bool Functions::prepareSocket(QString address, int port, QTcpSocket *socket) {
    socket->connectToHost(address, port);
    if(!socket->waitForConnected(Global::maxTimueToConnectByTCP)){
        qDebug()<<"Error: "<<socket->errorString();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then, correct me if I'm wrong, when I call a function into Functions to connect the MyThread's QTcpSocket to a host, I'm supposing I am on the same thread, since I'm calling the function from the thread I've created and not a different one.

Despite this, on socket->connectToHost I am getting **QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.** twice.

Why is that? What's wrong?

Comment: Where do you create the socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: QObject::moveToThread. This should do the trick.

Comment: Ok, that worked. I have read about that method, but I thought it was for different purposes. I don't understand why QTcpSocket created into a QThread is not attached to that Thread if you don't call moveToThread(this) after creating it. Why is this behaviour?

Comment: Because you need an eventloop in your new thread. See this article: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/thread-basics.html

Comment: moveToThread(this) is always wrong and not safe. You can "push" objects other threads, not pull them.

Comment: That is true, it is not the good way but the simple way. You should not derive from qthread. But if you do movetothread is the only way to get qobject working

Comment: muma: There shouldn't be a "but if you do". Conceptually, QThread is *not* a thread itself, but a thread controller. It makes no sense for a thread controller to live in the thread it controls. You need a controller to stay alive after the thread terminates, e.g. to signal to you that the thread did terminate.

Answer (score 1):

You should not derive from QThread. Implement everything on a class derived from QObject. You can then optionally call `moveToThread()` on that QObject to move it to a new thread. You'll find, though, that there's normally no need to move it to a new thread *anyway*, because now you'll have asynchronous, nonblocking code that won't stall your GUI thread.

They key to doing it is to never use `waitxxx` calls. Whenever you want to **wait** for something, you'll find that there's a **signal** that gets emitted when that thing happens (or fails). Connect a **slot** to that signal. You may need to do it multiple times -- different slots for different signals. That's how you correctly code asynchronous, event driven applications.

You only resort to using blocking calls when no other API exists. Database drivers and name resolvers are notoriously bad in this respect, but they are the lonely counterexamples. Let them die in solitude, I say.